# What syntax is used with adjacent difference?

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ program to determine the lowest and highest trading prices, and determine the differences between those prices by querying the user for 15 trading prices,computing the difference through the use of adjacent difference, printing out the differences, computing the lowest and highest recorded prices through the use of sort, and print out those values.

I am familiar with the use of sort, but I am not familiar with adjacent_difference. I read my textbook several times, searched the Internet and attempted to alter my code many times, but I am still getting errors and I am lost.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
  vector <int> p (15);
  vector <int>::iterator it1;

  cout<<"This program determines the daily differences, lowest and highest of 15 user-entered trading prices."<<endl;

  for (int i=0; i<p.size(); i++)
    {
      cout<<"Please enter a trading price."<<endl;
      cin>>p[i];
    }

 adjacent_difference(p.begin(), p.end(), p(it1));
 for (int i=0; i<p.size(); i++)
   {
    cout<<"The difference in daily trading prices is: "<<adjacent_difference(it1)<<endl;
   }

  sort (p.begin(), p.end());
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"The lowest trading price recorded was "<<p[0]<<"."<<endl;
  cout<<"The highest trading price recorded was "<<p[14]<<"."<<endl;

return 0;

}
```

Here are the errors:

- 28:47: error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector) (std::vector::iterator&)’
  adjacent_difference(p.begin(), p.end(), p(it1));
- 31:81: error: no matching function for call to ‘adjacent_difference(std::vector::iterator&)’
   cout<<"The difference in daily trading prices is: "<

Can someone please explain the syntax involved?
Thank you!

Comment: [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference) - It takes a destination to write to, the same way the first argument is where to begin reading from. There's also an example on there that you can run and edit.

Comment: What is `p(it1)` supposed to be? `p` is a vector, not a function.

Comment: @Barmar I am trying to add a third destination in accordance with the syntax of adjacent_difference, but I am not understanding the syntax so I am asking for help. (:

Comment: @reference Ok...I think that I kinda understand. Can you please explain more?

Comment: `adjacent_difference` is just a function, its syntax is just like any other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `adjacent_difference` is incorrect.  Try this instead:

```
vector <int> p (15);
vector <int> result(15);

for (int i=0; i < p.size(); ++i) {
  cout << "Please enter a trading price." << endl;
  cin >> p[i];
}

adjacent_difference(p.begin(), p.end(), result.begin());

for (vector<int>::const_iterator i = result.begin(); i != result.end(); ++i) {
    cout << *i << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you! When I commented out the printing of the adjacent difference and compiled, I received no errors. I am now trying to print out the calculated adjacent difference values, but I am confused and tried numerous ideas. Can you please explain what I would need to put where I originally had: cout<<"The difference in daily trading prices is: "<<adjacent_difference(it1)<<endl; ?

Answer (score 3):

The arguments to `adjacent_difference` are all iterators. The first two you've supplied correctly: they're the beginning and end of the range of inputs.

The third argument is an output iterator where you're doing to put the results. For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

// Just some arbitrary inputs:
std::vector<int> inputs { 1, 2, 17, 15, 4, 19, 0, 2};
std::vector<int> results;

std::adjacent_difference(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(),
    std::back_inserter(results));
```

If you're just going to print out the results anyway, you can do that directly by specifying an ostream_iterator for the third argument:

```
std::adjacent_difference(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"));
```

Do note, however, that the first value you get from `std::adjacent_difference` is the first input. Each subsequent result is the difference from the previous.

Also note that you don't need to completely sort the input just to find the highest and lowest prices. The most obvious way to do that would be with `std::minmax_element, something like this:

```
auto hilo = std::minmax_element(inputs.begin(), inputs.end());

std::cout << "Lowest price: " << *hilo.first << "\n"
          << "highest price: " << *hilo.second << "\n";
```

Comment: Do you know of any way to discard that first output value? I'm thinking maybe there should be a `std::inserter` that discards the first value, but no luck in finding that. For now, I've just copied [the reference implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference#Possible_implementation) and edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you defined (or imported) a function "adjacent_difference". However the compiler could not resolve both procedure calls :

```
 adjacent_difference(p.begin(), p.end(), p(it1));
 adjacent_difference(it1)
```

So basically, based on the arguments the procedure could not decide (unambiguously) which constructor to choose for the call. The reason for this can be that the number of arguments does not match, or the arguments themselves do not match (the types differ).

C++ uses the "Koenig Lookup" to check if a procedure matches a call.
I strongly advice you to take a look at these : [Koenig Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) , [Detailed explanation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

You have to know there can be an exact match (argument types match perfectly) but that isn't necessary. The compiler can sometimes be smart enough to cast it to the needed type.

I guess the first error is because the compiler cannot cast the iterator to the correct type.

But it can be trickier with for example virtual methods.

Comment: It's in `<numeric>`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference